# Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<Object[]>

Tags: java, types

Im getting always a type safety warning when I want to start a Hibernate application. Is there a method to get rid of this without using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` ?

here is my Code:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class);
        config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        new SchemaExport(config).create(false, false);

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        Query q = session
                .createQuery("SELECT e.empId,e.empName FROM Employee e");

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Object[]> list = q.list(); <-- here is the problem!
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hibernate's `Session.list()` returns a plain, raw `List`.

It is perfectly legal Java syntax to cast it to a parameterized collection (`List<Object[]>` here). But due to the fact that generic type infos are wiped out at runtime, the compiler will emit a warning to tell you it cannot guarantee this cast will actually be valid.
So it's just his way to tell you "Hey, you're playing with fire here, I hope you know what you do, because I don't".

In this particular case, you can't do anything to eliminate this warning, but you can take the responsibility of explicitely ignoring it by using the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to remove it unless you make q.list() exactly a `List<Object[]>`

Answer (score 1):

Another overloaded `createQuery()` method's accept result type.

```
createQuery(String queryString, Class<T> resultType)
```

I don't know which hibernate version added it.
Actually it is same result using `@SuppressWarnings`.

```
List<Employee> emp = session.createQuery("from Employee", Employee.class).getResultList();
```

By the way, at Hibernate 5.2  <del>list()</del> is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the cast to make the warning go away, but much like suppressing the warning it hides a potential issue since q.list() isn't guaranteed to return that exact type.

```
List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>)q.list();
```

Comment: I tried this and the cast did not remove the warning. It just changed the warning to Unchecked cast.